# How is this sorting by indexes? How exactly this code works?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook

```
arr = np.array(range(12))
arr = arr.reshape((4,3))
keys = np.array([1,0,1,2])
arr[np.arange(4), np.array([1,0,1,2])]
```

This prints :

```
array([ 1,  3,  7, 11]).
```

I understand that this is sorting according to indexes (1,1) (0,0) (1,1) (2,2)

But how? I'm not referring to any variable. I'm calling the function np.array and it nows I'm referring to the indexes of arr. Why is it not creating a new array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not sorting.  It is selecting elements from the array.

The row and column indices in these 2 lists are paired up,

```
 [0,1,2,3], [1,0,1,2]
```

It returns 4 elements

```
 arr[(0,1)], arr[(1,0)], arr[(2,1)], arr[(3,2)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply